# Node.js multiple domain web hosting

Tags: node.js

I have a VPS server (ubuntu)

wanted multiple node.js sites to be running on it, thus multiple domains
Was trying out

kubernetes with ha and docker images(containers) per website /But memory consumption would increase and the deployment is complex.
What i Need

I don't care if the database instance is shared
each website can have a own database in the database instance.

Node.js must run in the background, has got some env variables.

Simplest routing based on domain names to node.js port like 3000, 4000, 5000 and so on ..

Comment: maybe this package helps you https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhost

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using NGINX as described here, [Setting up an Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://linuxize.com/post/nginx-reverse-proxy/)